# Finding corresponding rows from two tables based on equals or summed up values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having the table structure

```
Table1
(Id int, 
AName varchar(100),
AValue DECIMAL(18,2), 
BName varchar(100),
BValue DECIMAL(18,2),
Type VARCHAR(1)
)
```

where Type is always 'A' or 'B'. I would like to find the corresponding AName and BName knowing that AValue = BValue or AValue represents a sum of BValue values or BValue represents a sum of AValue.

If Type = 'A' then only Id, AName and AValue columns have values, if Type = 'B' then only Id, BName and BValue columns have values.

I've tried splitting this into two tables where TableA contains only A Type values and TableB contains only B Type values but I can't find a way to identify the corresponding matching rows when AValue represents a sum of BValue values or values BValue represents a sum of AValue values.

```
 CREATE TABLE TableA 
 (Id INT NOT NULL,
 AName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 AValue DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
 BName VARCHAR(200), 
 BValue DECIMAL(18,2),
 Type VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
 );

 CREATE TABLE TableB 
 (Id INT NOT NULL,
 AName VARCHAR(200),
 AValue DECIMAL(18,2),
 BName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
 BValue DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
 Type VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
 );


INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1,'A',100,null, null,'A');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1,'B',15,null, null,'A');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1,'C',13,null, null,'A');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1,'D',15,null, null,'A');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (2,'C',2,null, null,'A');
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (2,'C',2,null, null,'A');


INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1,null, null,'D',50,'B');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1,null, null,'E',50,'B');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1,null, null,'F',13,'B');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1,null, null,'G',15,'B');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1,null, null,'H',15,'B');
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (2,null, null,'M', 4,'B');
```

The output should be (Id, AName,AValue, BName, BValue).
I've tried matching by Id with equality or sum:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.AName, a.AValue, b.BName, b.BValue
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE (a.AValue = b.BValue)
    OR (a.AValue = (SELECT SUM(BValue) FROM TableB WHERE Id = b.Id));
```

but the output of this isn't the desired one. The desired one should be

```
(1, 'A', 50, 'D', 50)
(1, 'A', 50, 'E', 50)
(1, 'B', 15, 'G', 15)
(1, 'C', 13, 'F', 13)
(1, 'D', 15, 'H', 15)
(2, 'C', 2, 'M', 2)
(2, 'C', 2, 'M', 2)
```